# i try to Archive the a project but i'm getting this error Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode8

I try to run the prog :

```
CodeSign /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/POC2-byrqqhzjppbjxjemdbcmskhttxdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/POC2.app/Frameworks/MicroBlink.framework

cd /Users/admin/Documents/Development/POC2
    export 

CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export 

PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"


Signing Identity:     "iPhone Distribution: **************name ***** (********)"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 4070CCDBD98188BA13DE80C8A094CCDFAC2A2E4C --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags --timestamp=none /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/POC2-byrqqhzjppbjxjemdbcmskhttxdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/POC2.app/Frameworks/MicroBlink.framework

/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/POC2-byrqqhzjppbjxjemdbcmskhttxdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/POC2.app/Frameworks/MicroBlink.framework: replacing existing signature

/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/POC2-byrqqhzjppbjxjemdbcmskhttxdm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/POC2.app/Frameworks/MicroBlink.framework: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Sure that you set right signing certificate in signing section in general .

Comment: i delete all the certificate and bundle id  but also im getting this error

Comment: Ok, try to uncheck Automatically manage signing and set signing certificate manually

Comment: yes i try it also but not at all working.i have been update the xcode 8 to 9 is that's the problem ?

Comment: I think not related

Comment: :'( mmmmm then any other way

Comment: I can contact you by TeamViewer

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have a iTunes connect profile & try to create an app with the same name & build settings in there & then try to archive your project as sometime the developer account does not match the profile of the app so then you might get this error.

You have to go to iTunes & create a profile & give it the same name as the project builder & then try to validate the archive project from the Xcode.

If the validation is success then you can submit it to the app store & if not let me know what error you get while you validate the app so that we can look more in deep.